# Exception when accessing SQLite database while switching between activities

Tags: android, database, onresume

My app consists of a number of activities, upto now I have had no problems with accessing the database when moving between the activities. However on the last listActivity (LocationActivity), I have an embedded button on each listView item.

When one of these buttons are clicked, it sends you to SpecificationEdit.java where the user inputs the specfication into some EditText fields for that listView item (a damaged component), but when you click Save it crashes with the following error message (note the data is saved to database ok):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity blah blah
Exception: trying to requery an already closed cursor blah blah
```

Here is the listActivity class:

```
public class LocationActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
    setLongClick();

    rmDbHelper = new RMDbAdapter(this);
    rmDbHelper.open();
    getIntents();
    setUpViews();
    setAdapter();               
    setTextChangedListeners();
}

protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    final Cursor locationCursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchLocationsForRun(runId);
    startManagingCursor(locationCursor);
    locationCursorSize = locationCursor.getCount();
    setAdapter();
    setTextChangedListeners();
}
```

And here is the bit in this activity where is sends you to SpecificationEdit.java

```
private void startComponentEdit() {
    Intent i = new Intent(LocationActivity.this, SpecificationEdit.class);
    i.putExtra("Intent_InspectionID", inspectionId);
    i.putExtra("Intent_AreaID", areaId);
    i.putExtra("Intent_RunID", runId);
    i.putExtra("Intent_LocationID", locationId);
    i.putExtra("Intent_Ref", locationRef);
    i.putExtra("Intent_DamagedComponentID", damagedComponentId);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

}
```

And here is the OnCreate in SpecificationEdit.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rmDbHelper = new RMDbAdapter(this);
    rmDbHelper.open();
    Intent i = getIntent();
    inspectionId = i.getLongExtra("Intent_InspectionID", -1);
    areaId = i.getLongExtra("Intent_AreaID", -1);
    runId = i.getLongExtra("Intent_RunID", -1);
    locationId = i.getLongExtra("Intent_LocationID", -1);
    damagedComponentId = i.getLongExtra("Intent_DamagedComponentID", -1);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_specification);
    setUpViews();
    populateFields();
    fillSpinner();
    setListeners();
}
```

With the bit of code which fires when you click the save button:

```
protected void saveDamagedComponentSpec() {  

    String manufacturer = ((Cursor)manufacturerSpinner.getSelectedItem()).getString(1).toString();
    String text1 = specEditText1.getText().toString();
    String text2 = specEditText2.getText().toString();
    String text3 = specEditText3.getText().toString();
    String text4 = specEditText4.getText().toString();
    String notes_spec = specEditTextNotes.getText().toString();

    rmDbHelper.saveDamagedComponentSpec(damagedComponentId, manufacturer, text1, text2, text3, text4, notes_spec);      

    if ("Yes".equals(specSaved)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Component specification updated", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Component specification added", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    finish();
}
```

Finally, here is the code in my database helper class:

```
//Constructor - takes the context to allow the database to be opened/created
public RMDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.mCtx = ctx;
}

/**
 * Open the rm database. If it cannot be opened, try to create a new
 * instance of the database. If it cannot be created, throw an exception to
 * signal the failure
 * 
 * @return this (self reference, allowing this to be chained in an
 *         Initialisation call)
 * @throws SQLException if the database could be neither opened or created
 */
public RMDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    rmDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
    rmDb = rmDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}


public void close() {
    rmDbHelper.close();
}
```

The weird thing is, you can click on one of the listView item (the actual item not the embedded item) or the button 'add new component' and this will send you to another activity ComponentEdit.java with very similar interface (to add a component to the list) as SpecificationEdit but which when it finishes doesn't crash the app.

I can't see any major difference between the two activities, yet one is crashing with this error when you return to LocationActivity and one is not.

I have just tried removing onResume and this made no difference.. Hit a brick wall with this and it's driving me nuts.

I should add that it is working ok on my emulator, but crashes when I test it on my phone (HTC One S).  Very strange..

Comment: are you manually closing locationCursor?

Comment: Thanks for quick response nandeesh.  I updated my code to do so, but this didn't make any difference..

Comment: if you are using startManagingCursor you should never close the cursor, activity will take care of it for you

Comment: do you ever stopManagingCursor ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, found the issue (spot the obvious mistake):

```
    Cursor componentsCursor = (Cursor) rmDbHelper.fetchDamagedComponentSpecForInspection(inspectionId, componentType);
    startManagingCursor(componentsCursor);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, SpecificationEdit.class);
    i.putExtra("Intent_InspectionID", inspectionId);
    i.putExtra("Intent_AreaID", areaId);
    i.putExtra("Intent_RunID", runId);
    i.putExtra("Intent_LocationID", locationId);
    i.putExtra("Intent_Ref", locationRef);
    i.putExtra("Intent_DamagedComponentID", damagedComponentId);
    startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);

    componentsCursor.close();
```

So it wasn't this obvious (I had some blocked out code left in before the componentsCursor.close()), but when I finished SpecifcationEdit.class, I guess it returns to this activity and tries to close the componentsCursor but obviously fails.

Stupid thing is, I hadn't actually got this cursor doing anything yet! Doh!

Just for some additional advice/whittering; my app is fundimentally different to the Google notePad example, as I don't actually use the startActivityForResult as they do (in fact now I understand it better I will replace these all with just startActivity) as I input the data into the database while still on the edit activities, there and then (rather than passing this information through an intent then addinig when you return to the previous activity.

I find this more logical in the realms of my code, but any feedback on this approach?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to call rmDbHelper.close(); before start another activity

Comment: Thanks for response letroll, but even if I close the database before I finish SpecificationEdit.java and return to LocationActivity, it doens't make any difference.  However, I haven't closed it when leaving earlier activities and it works ok when I come back from one activity but not the other..

Comment: Have you attempt to add rmDbHelper.close in startComponentEdit()? and in SpecificationEdit's onDestroy ?